# Loading isAuthenticated correctly in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to use `passport` with `passport-local` in my express app:

In my main app I load it the following:

```
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
// configure passport
// require('./config/passport')(passport)
const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const index = require('./routes/index')

const app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(logger(process.env.LOG_ENV))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../public')))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(session({
  secret: 'super-mega-hyper-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

My `passport.js` config file looks pretty typical:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const serviceAuth = require('../service/auth')

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await serviceAuth.findById(id)
    done(null, user)
  })

  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
  }, async(username, password, done) => {
    const user = await serviceAuth.signin(username, password)
    done(null, user)
  }))
```

Within my routes I would like to steer which routes need authentication:

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()
const utils = require('../util/utils')

router.get('/', utils.isLogged(), (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard')
})

module.exports = router
```

In the `utils/utils.js` folder I have the middleware to steer, which user  is authenticated.

```
const passportConfig = require('../config/passport')

function isLogged(req, res, next) {
  const auth = this.passportConfig.isAuthenticated()
  if (req.auth) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.redirect('/')
  }
}

module.exports = {
  isLogged,
}
```

However, here I get the following error:

```
  const auth = this.passportConfig.isAuthenticated()
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
```

Any suggestions how to load passport properly in my `utils/utils.js` folder?

I appreciate your replies!

**Update**

Please find the following [github repo](https://github.com/marcpre/learning_npm_passport-local), which shows the minimum viable example.

Answer (score 0):

In your `isLogged()` function, `this` keyword refers to the `function` itself, hence `this.passportConfig` is `undefined`. What you should do is just using:

```
const auth = passportConfig.isAuthenticated();
```

without `this` keyword.